# Selecting the first row from each group, with ORDER BY more than one column

Tags: sql, performance, group-by, sql-order-by, sybase

I have a table `T` with columns `x`,`y`,`a`,`b` such that

```
SELECT x,y,a,b FROM T
ORDER BY x,y,a,b
```

gives me the following table

```
 x    | y    | a    | b
 x1   | y1   | a1   | b1
 x1   | y1   | a1   | b2
 x1   | y1   | a2   | b1
 x1   | y2   | a1   | b1
 x1   | y2   | a1   | b2
 x1   | y2   | a2   | b1
```

How would I get the first row of each x,y group? That is, how would I get the following table

```
 x    | y    | a    | b
 x1   | y1   | a1   | b1
 x1   | y2   | a1   | b1
```

---

Here is a second example: For a table T such that

```
 x    | y    | a    | b
 x1   | y1   | a1   | b3
 x1   | y1   | a1   | b4
 x1   | y1   | a2   | b1
 x1   | y1   | a2   | b2
 x1   | y2   | a1   | b3
 x1   | y2   | a1   | b4
 x1   | y2   | a2   | b1
 x1   | y2   | a2   | b2
```

I am expecting to get

```
 x    | y    | a    | b
 x1   | y1   | a1   | b3
 x1   | y2   | a1   | b3
```

Comment: I see you are attempting to post a formatted table structure in a comment to my answer. Please edit the original question to include that as comments do not support code-formatting. This way, I will have a better understanding of your ***actual*** data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Considering SQL 2005 or Above:

```
SELECT T1.X,
       T1.Y,
       T1.A,
       T1.B
  FROM
      (SELECT X,
              Y,
              A,
              B,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY X,Y Order By A,B) AS RowNum
         FROM T
     ) T1
WHERE T1.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: I like how readable it looks, but is this the most efficient solution?

Comment: +1, @DanielVaca - It should be very efficient. (if your database supports that syntax that is)

Comment: Equivalent to Nitin's solution, but a bit more compact is this, which uses SQL Server's proprietary TOP .. WITH TIES:

SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  x,y,a,b
FROM T
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY x,y
    ORDER BY a,b
  )

Comment: Unfortunately, SteveKass's solution did not work on sybase, but NitinMidha's solution did give me the fastest results. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As per your comments and new table structure, you can use this simple DBMS-agnostic solution:

```
SELECT a.x,a.y,a.a,MIN(a.b) b
FROM T a
JOIN ( SELECT x,y,MIN(a) a FROM T GROUP BY x,y ) b ON
    a.x = b.x AND
    a.y = b.y AND
    a.a = b.a
GROUP BY a.x,a.y,a.a
```

---

### [SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1a88/2/0)

Comment: I'm having a hard time getting the markup to work, but it doesn't seem to be working for this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f38b/4 
 . 
I am using sybase, so a solution using INTERSECT would be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: This worked out great, but NitinMidha's solution gave me a faster result on sybase. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very efficient Oracle solution

```
select x, 
       y, 
       min(a) as a, 
       min(b) keep( dense_rank first order by a) as b
  from T
 group by x,y
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this and let me know

```
select x,y,MIN(a) a,MIN(b) b
from T
group by X,y
```

Comment: This wont work because for my second example,  [it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f38b/10) gives the wrong answer.