# SQL getting first full row matching each result in subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

So the question is this. I have a table with n columns of data, but I want to list one row for each unique set of 3 columns.

For example, say the table is structured as below

```
ID | data1 | data2 | data3 | description | price | handler | creationTime | etc...
```

What I'm trying to do, is to use this subquery:

```
SELECT distinct data1, data2, data3 FROM Table_1
```

... to get each unique variation for the 3 columns. But then I want to select ONE full row from the table for each such result.

This query is meant for rather heavy use and needs to be optimized, which is kind of why I can't use table variables or while loops. Any hints?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424506/selecting-the-first-row-from-each-group-with-order-by-more-than-one-column/11424557#11424557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using SQL Server, you can do this with a common table expression:

```
with minRow(ID) as 
    (select min(ID)
    from    Table_1
    group by data1, data2, data3)
select  t1.*
from    Table_1 t1 join minRow m1 on t1.ID = m1.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you understand the concept of DISTINCT. If you have:

```
ID  data1  data2 data3 description1 price1
ID  data1  data2 data3 description2 price2
```

what do you expect as result? `ID  data1  data2 data3` will be returned only once, but what should happend with the other columns that are distinct among those that are equal?

You can always do

```
select distinct ID,  data1,  data2, data3, MAX(description1), MAX(price1)
```

it will parse and give you a result but it actually wont make much sense...

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What don't I understand about the concept of DISTINCT, exactly? And the query is odd, I admit. In reality there will be filters on the first row returned, but I tried to keep the example simple here. Once there's a way to efficiently filter the first result for each set of 3 datas, adding further filters to that is a simple matter. :)

Comment: what I meant is that if you get the distinct values on columns A B and C between the rows, you are somehow grouping all rows that have the same value on A B and C togheter. What do you excpect to be returned on the columns that are not being grouped? You need to apply some sort of aggregation to it.

Comment: Oh right, yes you're right. Like I said in the prior comment, there will be further filters defined to determine which column and value determines the first pick for each set of 3. But I have no idea what they will be as of yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is windows functions.  Here is the query that returns the "first" row from each group:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by data1, data2, data3
                                order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      FROM Table_1 t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

(This also includes the final seqnum column with a "1" in it.)

The idea is to provide a sequence number for each row and take th first one.  The "order by" clause is required.  The syntax in this query is just an efficient way of saying "I don't care about the order" in SQL Server -- this differs in other databases.